# How to create datepicker on dynamiclly created textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

**This is my textfield:**

```
<input type='text' id='activationdate' name='activationdate' style='height:"+height*2.5/100+"px;font-size:"+height*2.3/100+"px' class='activationdate'/>
```

**Dynamically created textfields will be like this:**

```
<input type='text' id='activationdate"+temp+"' name='activationdate' style='height:"+height*2.5/100+"px;font-size:"+height*2.3/100+"px' class='activationdate'/>
```

*temp is increased +1 wtih javascript each time a dynamic textbox is created and temp starts from 1*

**Now this is my jquery datepicker code:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[id^="activationdate"]').on('click', function() { 
    $(this).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
});
```

But it is not working. Please help..................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach for **dynamically created elements**.

Use

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[id^="activationdate"]', function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

### EDIT

Apply plugin after creation of element instead of using event delgation

```
function addDataUpper(){
    //Your Existing code

    //Add Plugin
    $('#activationdate'+temp).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });     
    return false;        
}
```

Comment: It's working.But the problem is it starts working when I'm clicking the textbox(both the primary one or dynamic ones) second time.On clicking it for the first time nothing is happeing.Is this because something is wrong with the code?

Comment: @AbhinabKanrar, Have you already applied `datepicker` for primary ones/

Comment: Intially I too thought so. But it's not used anywhere. I've repeatedly checked

Comment: @AbhinabKanrar, Can you show code how you are creating them? Its best to apply plugin after creating them.

Comment: adding the code as an answer because it will messed up here

Comment: added the code. Please check and tell me what's wrong with the code. It's a simple piece of code and I'm not doing any heavy thing there.So what's wrong with it.Please help[ here

Comment: @AbhinabKanrar, I have updated answer. And delete your answer